# I got my wheels balanced and aligned and my car is still shaking

Tags: tires, jeep, alignment, shaking, wheel-balance

My car is a jeep patriot 2014 and only had one previous owner with no wrecks, ive only had the car since January and about a month ago my car started to shake while on back roads. I checked all my tires pressures and found the passenger was low and topped it off and figured that would help.. a week goes by and its started to shake on the highway when going over 50mph so I was suggested to get my tires balced and aligned so I did and the front passenger tire ended up having old weights on the inside as well as a new one on the outside.. so they fixed that as well as balancing them and aligning them and all seemed okay up untill now. Yesterday I was on back roads going under 35 and it started to shake for a bit and ended up going away and today I went on the highway going 80 and it didn't shake untill I got off.. im not really sure what's wrong with it at this point any tips would be much appreciated
thank you!

Comment: Check your lug nuts are torqued properly.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Generally during a wheel alignment they will check the steering and suspension components for wear, damage, or other problems that may impact the handling.  Let's assume for now that they did NOT do that and you have something wrong in your suspension.  You'll need to take it to a shop that has reputable mechanics who can check your suspension and see what's wrong.